# Solving the ordinary differential equation $y'=y$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So one way to solve this ordinary differential equation is by computing the integral of both sides of $$\frac{y'}{y} = 1$$
However, I did it another way and I think I made a mistake, but where is it? What I did is:
$$y' = y $$
$$ \int y'dx = \int y dx $$
$$ \int \frac{dy}{dx}dx = \int y dx $$
$$ \int dy = \int y dx $$
$$ y = yx + C $$
$$ y = \frac{C}{1-x}$$

Comment: The integral of $ydx$ isn't $yx$ because $y$ is a function of $x$

Comment: Oh I see... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating $y$ as a constant when you say

$$\int y \, dx = xy+C$$

In reality, $y$ is a function of $x$. For instance, this claims that

$$\int e^x \, dx = xe^x + C$$

when we let $y(x)=e^x$, but this claim is obviously problematic.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity, you can also apply the integrating factor method:
\begin{align*}
y' = y & \Longleftrightarrow y' - y = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{-x}y' - e^{-x}y = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (e^{-x}y)' = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow e^{-x}y = k\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y(x) = ke^{x}
\end{align*}
where $k\in\textbf{R}$.

Hopefully this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

If $y'=\frac{dy}{dx}$ as you wrote $y$ is a function in the variable $x$ so $\int y(x) dx$ is not $yx$. I think the only way is to integrate $\frac{y'}{y}$.

Comment: Not so. If we set $z=ye^{-x}$ then $z'=y'e^{-x}-ye^{-x}=0$. This means that $z=c$ and $y=ce^x$. This leverages the fact that a function with a zero derivative is constant, which is elementary, and doesn't require integration.